# Escalar CarouselView dependiendo del tamaño de la imagen descargada con Glide

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-glide

Tengo en mi proyecto un RecyclerView, y para llenar este mismo uso un Layout como el siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


//como pueden ver aqui le tengo puesto en height WRAP_CONTENT
        <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
            android:id="@+id/carouselView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:fillColor="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
            card_view:pageColor="#00000000"
            card_view:radius="6dp"
            card_view:slideInterval="4000"
            card_view:strokeColor="#FF777777"
            card_view:strokeWidth="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Nombre_negocio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/carouselView"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Titulo de Prueba"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Descr_corta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Nombre_negocio"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

es simplemente un LinearLayout con un CardView dentro y dentro de este esta el CarouselView y abajo dos TextViews...
El objetivo es llenar mi CarouselView con tres imágenes... para esto uso glide de esta forma:

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.KreativerCorp.UpyApp.Entites.Person;
import com.KreativerCorp.UpyApp.R;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.jude.easyrecyclerview.adapter.BaseViewHolder;
import com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView;
import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageListener;




public class PersonViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<Person>  {
private TextView mTv_name;
private CarouselView mImg_face;
private TextView mTv_sign;



//encuentro las Views.
public PersonViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    super(parent, R.layout.item_person);
    mTv_name = $(R.id.Nombre_negocio);
    mTv_sign = $(R.id.Descr_corta);
    mImg_face = $(R.id.carouselView);
}


//aqui obtengo los datos de otro codigo... que lo unico que hace es pasar dos Strings y un "URL" de la imagen a descargar con glide
@Override
public void setData(final Person person){
    Log.i("ViewHolder","position"+getDataPosition());
    mTv_name.setText(person.getName());
    mTv_sign.setText(person.getSign());






//segun la libreria CarouselView con esto digo cuantas imagenes voy a tener.
    mImg_face.setPageCount(3);

//y aqui lleno las tres imagenes con la libreria Glide.
    mImg_face.setImageListener( new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(person.getFace())// getface me da el URL de la imagen
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.medir)
                            .into(imageView);


            break;
                case 1:
                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(person.getFace2())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.medir)
                            .into(imageView);


                    break;
                case 2:
                    Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(person.getFace3())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.medir)
                            .into(imageView);

                    break;
                default:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.medir);
                 break;
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

Quiero que las imágenes que se obtengan con Glide al colocarlas en las ImageViews del CarouselView se escalen hasta llenar el ancho de mi Layout, y que el alto de la imagen escale para no distorsionarse.

PD: si cambio el height del CarouselView por un numero de Dp´s pasa que la imagen se corta y no se muestra completa(no quiero que esto pase, quiero que se muestre la imagen completa).